# Can a variable be passed as an element id in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I'm trying to get some AJAX running with Django using jQuery. The problem is that the ID of the element I'm trying to change isn't set in stone, it's a Django template variable so it is different for each element in the table, but I want to use AJAX to change that element. I'm passing the dictionary from a Django view to JavaScript via simplejson, the pertinent objects being ID and model (not real variable names, just wanted to make it obvious what I am trying to do). Some pseudo code (third line, wrote it like python because I don't know how to do this in JavaScript):

```
var quantity_update = function(msg, elem) {
    var response_obj = eval('(' + msg + ')');
    var newtotal = document.getElementById("%s, %s"); % (response_obj.id, response_obj.model)
    subtotal.innerHTML = "<td>"+response_obj.subtotal+"</td>";
```

Is something like this possible, and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript doesn't have fancy string formatting (%s), but you can use plain string concatenation, just like you can in Python:

```
var id = response_obj.id + ', ' + resonse_obj.model
```

You don't need to worry about the string being generated dinamically. It is still a string after all and getElementById accepts it the same way .

---

You probably shouldn't be doing the eval() yourself to parse the JSON. I'm pretty sure you can have JQuery do that for you when you do the AJAX request.

Comment: then I should be able to get the id like this: var newtotal = document.getElementById(id); maybe. Using eval because sometime i pass strings not dictionaries in case of errors in the view

Comment: Yes, a variable containing a string and a string literal are perfectly interchangeable. As for the errors, you can try having your server signal this via a HTTP response code. This can be detected in the client side so you can do different things depending on wether there was an error or not.

Comment: I guess this isn't the problem at all. I had done something similar with join() and got the same results, it would be the line in this example that should be newtotal.innerHTML but instead is subtotal any(correct in my actual code) comes back as null.

Comment: also given i think this was the answer to my question this is what i was looking for, thanks

Comment: @Christopher: You can accept answers by clicking on the green checkmark next to them. This helps organize the site and also gives me some rep points :P

Comment: thank for the tip, first post, usually find answers without asking questions but i was wondering how to give you credit

Comment: turns out the join() method also works just didn't have the id in the html consistant with what the javascript was looking for(very accurate with it's spaces), thanks again for the help, django+ajax=headache

Answer (score 0):

If your element ID is not set in stone, you might want to identify the element using other means. Many JS framework such as jQuery supports identification via CSS Selector. For example you can identify the element you want to change by combination of its tag and class.

For documentation on the available selector you should read [jQuery Selector Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

You can totally pass jquery css selectors as variables.  Simple example:

```
var elementId = $('td').eq(0).attr('id'),
    myElement = $('#'+elementId);
```

In this example, we grab the ID of the first TD in your document, find its id, and use that to get "myElement"

You may find it helpful to review the "selectors" section of the jQuery documentation (api.jquery.com) to review all your options for finding an element. In my example I also am using the jquery.eq() method, which filters a list of selectors (in this case all the TDs) to a specific one.